# update the attribute name and element value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to update Address with Address Line 1 and the value inside to 1 Jane place and save it in a variable. Input is any dummy xml

used this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="request">
            <customers>
                <customer name="Address">1 Doe Place</customer>
                <customer name="State">OH</customer>
                <customer name="Name">John</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
                <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
                <customer name="city">Columbus</customer>
            </customers>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="response">
        -------
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$response"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

dont know what exactly to update here. I know how to do with identity transform but here i'm confused

Comment: Why are you hard-coding data in your stylesheet, instead of using an external lookup XML document - which you can simply update when the address (or any other item) changes?

Comment: Actually I'm reading from a variable which comes from earlier calls. And then I need to update it

Comment: And where does the update come from? Also, the description "*a variable which comes from earlier calls*" is not clear. This is crucial in XSLT 1.0, since the variable could contain either a node-set or a result-tree-fragment.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this could work for you (I am still puzzled regarding what this is really about):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="request">
    <customers>
        <customer name="Address">1 Doe Place</customer>
        <customer name="State">OH</customer>
        <customer name="Name">John</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
        <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
        <customer name="city">Columbus</customer>
    </customers>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="response">
    <customers>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($request)/customers/customer">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@name='Address'">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                        <xsl:text>1 Jane place</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </customers>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$response"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The **result**, when applied to any XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
   <customer name="Address">1 Jane place</customer>
   <customer name="State">OH</customer>
   <customer name="Name">John</customer>
   <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
   <customer name="Name">Leon</customer>
   <customer name="Name">Adam</customer>
   <customer name="city">Columbus</customer>
</customers>
```